# Is this a good explanation of electron mobility to the layman?

Tags: electricity, soft-question, electrons, classical-electrodynamics, popular-science

I'm writing an informative paper on graphene for my writing class (layman-oriented), and was describing electron mobility in very simplified terms. Let me know if anything is mistaken, badly represented, or just any advice, thanks!

---

"This value [electron mobility] does not mean that electricity will move faster in graphene. Rather, it means that individual electrons will move faster in graphene than in other elements. As an example, you can think of the flow of electricity as people standing in a line, passing buckets of water – individual electrons – to the next person to stop a growing fire. From the moment the first bucket is passed, many others would have moved along the line simultaneously. What electron mobility is, is how fast an individual bucket of water is passed down from one person to the next and how fast a person would be available to receive the next bucket and pass it on, rather than the speed of the movement of the line as a whole."

Comment: Another way, slightly different but maybe simpler, is to say that mobility is how fast a single line moves and conductivity is that speed multiplied by the number of lines.

Comment: That seems like a decent explanation, but I don't know if it would be simpler.

Comment: Please don't take this as a criticism of your effort which is valiant. The problem with these mental models is that they suggest that electricity moves because charge carriers move, which is not the case. Electricity, i.e. electromagnetic waves move because they are fields that are propagating at the speed of light (in vacuum). What conductors do is to restrict the movement of these waves to the immediate neighborhood of the conductor. This is neither easy to understand nor is it easy to explain without mathematics and it has very little to do with electron mobility.

Comment: Jon, just a minor point : you say elements when you should say materials.

Comment: "Electricity moves faster" is sorta nonsensical. Maybe you mean "more electrical current flows"?

Comment: @SteveB, yes, you're right, but this is an overly simplified explanation for the average person. Maybe I should say "electricity flows faster.

Comment: @JohnDuffield, yes, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @CuriousOne, I actually did not know that about electricity and conductors! I thought electron mobility relates the velocity of electrons with the electric field, which allows a bigger current, or faster signal. Please correct me on any mistake.

Comment: Higher electron mobility allows larger currents and faster switching of electronic components, but the actual propagation of electricity is a field effect. You are certainly not expected to know this (or be able to explain it) and you would be surprised how many physicists and electrical engineers don't have a working model of this, either. Like I said, it's not easy to understand and explain.

Comment: @CuriousOne, currently I'm a physics and electrical engineering student, so I guess I won't be learning too much of that. However, I do intend to pursue a graduate degree in theoretical physics, so that should give me a better understanding hopefully.

Comment: Good luck and have fun!